# How can I compile hdparm for windows?

Tags: windows, compilation, cygwin

I have the latest binary (9.43). How can I use it on windows? The cygwin distribution of hdparm is too old (6.x) for what I want to do. Is there a way to use cygwin to run the 9.43 version of hdparm? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't compile hdparm for Windows. While hdparm is distributed with its source code, the code is specifically for Linux. The author hasn't written code for other operating systems, so the program runs on Linux only.

You might be able to get the program to run under cygwin on Windows, but it looks to me to be a substantial effort as hdparm accesses hardware pretty directly with IOCTL commands and so on.

Comment: This guy did it using cygwin. But there's no documentation on the process. Also, it's an outdated version of hdparm, that's why I can't use it. http://disablehddapm.blogspot.com/